# Active Contours

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

In the below link: [Active Contour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_contour_model)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_contour_model

Internal Energy of the snake is 
$$E_{internal}=\frac{(\alpha\,\!(s)\left | \mathbf{v}_s(s) \right \vert^2 + \beta\,\!(s)\left | \mathbf{v}_{ss}(s) \right \vert ^2)}{2}$$

Why it is divided by 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a big deal indeed. Sometimes the $\frac {1}{2}$ term is [omitted](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~grauman/courses/378/handouts/snakes.pdf), thus the membrane term $\alpha$ and thin plate term $\beta$ are halved to achieve the same effect. The core is the trade-off between contracting behavior and sharp bends avoidance, which are reflected with the first and second derivative terms.

Comment: check this link please http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14736/metrics-for-noisy-images

Comment: I need to know this to progress with my project